# How to remove sub-string starting and ending with something?

Tags: python, string

How can I remove a sub-string from a string starting and ending with a certain character combination like:

```
' bla <span class=""latex""> ... This can be different1 ... </span> blub <span class=""latex""> ... This can be different2 ... </span> bleb'
```

That I want as result:

```
'bla blub bleb'
```

I tried something like this

```
string.replace('<span class=""latex"">' * '</span>', '')
```

but this does not work.

Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Justin have you tried python's `re` package and specifically the `re.sub()` function? You will need regular expressions to do this. There are plenty of answered question on the topic of regex and html.

Comment: I updated my answer for the updated question. Plz check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could work:

```
>>> import re
>>> x=re.sub(r"""<span class=""latex"">.+?</span>""", "", s)

>>> x
' bla  blub  bleb'
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TTmJXw/3)

*EDIT* : after clarification by the OP, changed the answer to use [lazy quantifier](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) instead of capturing group. While this works, it is not scalable to [more complex cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). If that is the case, the proper solution would be to parse the string and extract what is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Read about [re.sub function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

A simple example:

```
import re

s = ' cvbcx cvbcx <span class=""latex""> ... This can be different ... </span>vcvbcxbvxc'
re.sub(r'<span class=""latex"">.+</span>', '<span class=""latex""></span>', s)

>> ' cvbcx cvbcx <span class=""latex""></span>vcvbcxbvxc'
```

Comment: This will replace the whole `<span ... </span>` with an empty string, not just the data in between the `<span>`.

Comment: @slider Yep, edited the answer so that a found pattern is replaced with the tag instead of an empty string

Comment: I updated the question, since I have the problem that I have multiple after each other and the sub strings in the middel (here 'blub') will be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use groups if you want some parts and not others.

```py
import re

s = ' cvbcx cvbcx <span class=""latex""> ... This can be different ... </span>vcvbcxbvxc'
r = re.search( r'(<span class=""latex"">)(.+)(</span>)', s)

print(s)
# cvbcx cvbcx <span class=""latex""> ... This can be different ... </span>vcvbcxbvxc

# print(r)
# <re.Match object; span=(13, 73), match='<span class=""latex""> ... This can be different >

print(r.group(1), r.group(3))
# <span class=""latex""> </span>
```

Comment: Groups are added by wrapping parts in parenthesis. Group indexing statrts at 1.

Comment: interesting approach. How can you use it if you have multiple after each other? (see updated question) Since I want to avoid skipping ones in the middle that code which is not in a <span>  is not removed. 
I tried this: `group = re.search(r"""(<span class=""latex"">)(.+)^((?!<span class=""latex"">).)*$(.+)(</span>)""", string)` but this didn't work do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the data in between:

```
    >>> x
'<span class=""latex""> ... This can be different ... </span>'
>>> 
>>> d = re.sub('<(/)?span(\ class=\"\".*\"\")?(>)', '', x)
>>> 
>>> d
' ... This can be different ... '
>>>
```

If you want to keep the tags:

```
>>> x
'<span class=""latex""> ... This can be different ... </span>'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> new_data = 'abc 123 456'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> d = re.sub('\">.*</','\">{}</'.format(new_data),x)
>>> 
>>> 
>>> d
'<span class=""latex"">abc 123 456</span>'
>>> 
>>> 
>>>
```